# How to split numbers in the arduino code?

Tags: c++, string, arduino, bluetooth, app-inventor

I'm having some problems on separating numbers that I recived from my app inventor using the hc-06 bluetooth module.
So my problem is the app inventor sends everything together, and I need to split them, but I don't know how to do this.

I'm writing to add some information for my doubt in order to be more informative.

So my problem is that I need to slip the numbers that I receive from the app inventor.  The app sends to my serial , for example, the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6. I created a variable (INT) for A,B,C,D,E,F; and I want to split each letter for each number. Then I print some letter, (A), and the results have to be the first number, in this case number 1.
I’ve already created a program, but it doesn't work, because when I print some letter (A), it shows me all the numbers (1,2,3,4,5,6).
In app inventor I put a semicolon between the textbox (numbers) trying to split them, and make the program easier in arduino code, but when I send the number with the semicolon, the same appears as a number 59. As a result, the serial shows this: 59,1,59,2,59,3,59,4,59,5,59,6.

what I need to do?

here is my app inventor blocks:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7qPI.png)

here is my app inventor designer:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdwS5.png)

here is my arduino code using ";" as a splitter:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLhLV.png)

And here is the result on Serial:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsZ9a.png)

- we can see that the semicolon is equal as a 59.

finally, here is the arduino code using "59" as a splitter:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcQMc.png)

the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJvn2.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried. Images are not liked much (and aren't useful). The best way to do that is by copy/paste, after you check it does exhibit the behaviour described. May I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: None of that appears to be C.

Comment: Firewalls are preventing me from following your links.  No code posted as text == no help.

Comment: When in doubt: 1) Search the internet for examples; 2) Write a program on the PC that exercises your solution.  Developing on the PC is generally easier than debugging on an embedded system.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update your question with information from when you have tried debugging this problem. For example, App Inventor is sending data with `Send1ByteNumber` and `SendText`. What value you expecting to turn up on the Arduino in variable `readString`? And what data are you actually getting?. The documentation for [Serial.read](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/read/) says it returns only the first byte of incoming serial data available.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways you could do this, but the important thing is that both sides of the Bluetooth link understands the data structure that is being sent.

Typically with with Bluetooth, if you have multiple values, you pack the data into a list so you can send them in an efficient way. You would then unpack them at the other end of the link.

I created a small app with four values that I wanted to send. The integer values were created by sliders.

[image]

I've put all the app blocks here for reference but the key block is the `SendBytes`. As I know my slider values are between 0 and 255 (which will fit into one byte) I can send all four values in a list of four bytes.

[image]

On the Arduino side of the link I will `readBytes` and I know where my values are in the list so I can unpack the list and cast each value from a byte to an int.

```c
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial hc06(3,2);
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 4;
byte dataBytes[BUFFER_SIZE];

void setup(){
  //Initialize Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //Initialize Bluetooth Serial Port
  hc06.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("setup done...");

}

void loop(){
  //Write data from HC06 to Serial Monitor
  if (hc06.available()){
    int data_len = hc06.readBytes(dataBytes, BUFFER_SIZE);
    int a = (int) dataBytes[0];
    int b = (int) dataBytes[1];
    int c = (int) dataBytes[2];
    int d = (int) dataBytes[3];
    Serial.print("A = ");
    Serial.println(a);
    Serial.print("B = ");
    Serial.println(b);
    Serial.print("C = ");
    Serial.println(c);
    Serial.print("D = ");
    Serial.println(d);
  }  
}
```

Which gave me the following output in the serial monitor when I sent some random data:

```
setup done...
A = 221
B = 147
C = 58
D = 3
```

---

If 255 is not a big enough number, then you can go up to 65,535 with two bytes (UInt16). Looking at App Inventor there doesn't appear to be a ready made way to turn a big integer into an array of UInt8 values. However, it is not a lot to do the conversion. As an example:

[image]

The conversion on the Arduino would look something like:

```c
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    lowByte(a) = dataBytes[0];
    highByte(a) = dataBytes[1];
    lowByte(b) = dataBytes[2];
    highByte(b) = dataBytes[3];
```

---

For checking if a text box is empty and replacing it with a default values, I would do something like the following:
[image]

Comment: hey @ukBaz, it works!! Your help was really important for me, I'm so grateful!                                            But now, appears another problem, because this works as you said in order to split byte to byte, but when I don't put some number, it seems that the program forget of this byte and doesn't put in order that I want.                                                                                        below I'm write better to be more informative.

Comment: Here is my pictures to explain better what is happing:            https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1JMg.png  ////////// https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGCx1.png   As you can see, in the first one I don't write anynumber, and theoretically it woud've appear on serial as letter A, but appears as letter D. In this case, the sequence must be A=0,B=2,C=3,D=4. To solve my problem, I try  this code on app inventor: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmTCI.png . My intention by this was :  "if I don't write a number on text.box,  put the number 88 on the text box". But it doesn't work, I think that is something similar.

Comment: The reason why I put the number 88 is for the program see a number and send to serial in the correct byte, but it could be any number.

Comment: Glad it is working for you. I see a different error to you when I leave a text box empty. It does not send any values because it cannot covert the empty value to an integer. I've updated the answer above with an example of checking for an empty string and replacing it with a zero. As you say, this is "another problem". On stackoverflow it is expected that you finish this question if it answered your original post and open a new question if there are other issues.